# Chrome extension for helping players search through a forum

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

As a player of the online game Pokéfarm Q, I'm making a fan-made extension to help players search through forum threads and CSS codes/userscripts. So that I can easily fetch data from a Pastebin I created, I added a function that ignores the CORS headers when the user is visiting https://pokefarm.com and the browser extension is requesting a page from pastebin.com.

I based the code off of a much larger extension allowing users to disable CORS on specific pages using the browser extension, by toggling it on/off in a context menu, but there's a lot of unnecessary extra pieces of code that don't need to be in there. Could anyone help me clean up my code a bit? I've done the very best I can so far, but I'm quite new to coding chrome extensions (this is the first one I developed all by myself) so I'm not sure what the best option is right now.

(if it isn't entirely clear, the code below is just the background.js file and not the main content script)

```
/* Source code based on (but not directly taken from) https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cors-unblock/lfhmikememgdcahcdlaciloancbhjino */
/* CORS has to be unblocked so that PFQ, Pastebin, the PFQ CDN, and the extension can all work together. */

"use strict";

const prefs = {
    enabled: true,
    "overwrite-origin": true,
    methods: ["GET", "PUT", "POST", "DELETE", "HEAD", "OPTIONS", "PATCH", "PROPFIND", "PROPPATCH", "MKCOL", "COPY", "MOVE", "LOCK"],
    "remove-x-frame": true,
    "allow-credentials": true,
    "allow-headers-value": "*",
    "allow-origin-value": "*",
    "expose-headers-value": "*",
    "allow-headers": true,
    "unblock-initiator": true,
};
const redirects = {};
chrome.tabs.onRemoved.addListener((tabId) => delete redirects[tabId]);
const cors = {};
cors.onBeforeRedirect = (d) => {
    if (d.type === "main_frame") {
        return;
    }
    redirects[d.tabId] = redirects[d.tabId] || {};
    redirects[d.tabId][d.requestId] = true;
};
cors.onHeadersReceived = (d) => {
    if (d.type === "main_frame") {
        return;
    }
    const { initiator, originUrl, responseHeaders, method, requestId, tabId } = d;
    let origin = "";
    const redirect = redirects[tabId] ? redirects[tabId][requestId] : false;
    if (prefs["unblock-initiator"] && redirect !== true) {
        try {
            const o = new URL(initiator || originUrl);
            origin = o.origin;
        } catch (e) {
            console.warn("cannot extract origin for initiator", initiator);
        }
    } else {
        origin = "*";
    }
    if (redirects[tabId]) {
        delete redirects[tabId][requestId];
    }
    if (prefs["overwrite-origin"] === true) {
        const o = responseHeaders.find(({ name }) => name.toLowerCase() === "access-control-allow-origin");
        if (o) {
            o.value = origin || prefs["allow-origin-value"];
        } else {
            responseHeaders.push({
                name: "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
                value: origin || prefs["allow-origin-value"],
            });
        }
    }
    if (prefs.methods.length > 3) {
        // GET, POST, HEAD are mandatory
        const o = responseHeaders.find(({ name }) => name.toLowerCase() === "access-control-allow-methods");
        if (o) {
            o.value = prefs.methods.join(", ");
        } else {
            responseHeaders.push({
                name: "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
                value: prefs.methods.join(", "),
            });
        }
    }
    if (prefs["allow-credentials"] === true) {
        const o = responseHeaders.find(({ name }) => name.toLowerCase() === "access-control-allow-credentials");
        if (o) {
            o.value = "true";
        } else {
            responseHeaders.push({
                name: "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials",
                value: "true",
            });
        }
    }
    // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Headers
    if (prefs["allow-headers"] === true) {
        const o = responseHeaders.find(({ name }) => name.toLowerCase() === "access-control-allow-headers");
        if (o) {
            o.value = prefs["allow-headers-value"];
        } else {
            responseHeaders.push({
                name: "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
                value: prefs["allow-headers-value"],
            });
        }
    }
    if (prefs["allow-headers"] === true) {
        const o = responseHeaders.find(({ name }) => name.toLowerCase() === "access-control-expose-headers");
        if (o) {
            o.value = prefs["expose-headers-value"];
        } else {
            responseHeaders.push({
                name: "Access-Control-Expose-Headers",
                value: prefs["expose-headers-value"],
            });
        }
    }
    if (prefs["remove-x-frame"] === true) {
        const i = responseHeaders.findIndex(({ name }) => name.toLowerCase() === "x-frame-options");
        if (i !== -1) {
            responseHeaders.splice(i, 1);
        }
    }
    return {
        responseHeaders,
    };
};
cors.install = () => {
    chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.removeListener(cors.onHeadersReceived);
    chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRedirect.removeListener(cors.onBeforeRedirect);

    const extra = ["blocking", "responseHeaders"];
    if (/Firefox/.test(navigator.userAgent) === false) {
        extra.push("extraHeaders");
    }
    chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(
        cors.onHeadersReceived,
        {
            urls: ["*://*.pastebin.com/*", "*://*.pokefarm.com/*", "*://*.pfq-static.com/*"],
        },
        extra
    );
    chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRedirect.addListener(cors.onBeforeRedirect, {
        urls: ["*://*.pastebin.com/*", "*://*.pokefarm.com/*", "*://*.pfq-static.com/*"],
    });
};

cors.onCommand = () => {
    cors.install();
};
chrome.storage.onChanged.addListener((ps) => {
    Object.keys(ps).forEach((name) => (prefs[name] = ps[name].newValue));
    cors.onCommand();
});

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(() =>
    chrome.storage.local.set({
        enabled: prefs.enabled === false,
    })
);

/* init */
chrome.storage.local.get(prefs, (ps) => {
    Object.assign(prefs, ps);
    cors.onCommand();
});
```

The goal of the background script is simply to bypass CORS and the Content Security Policy when a content script on https://pokefarm.com sends a request to https://pastebin.com, but the code that I'm basing it on had a lot of configuration options that I'm not 100% sure what to do about.